# Java EE - CDI Event Observes

Tags: events, cdi, event-listener, java-ee-7

Why when I execute the event, it calls two methods that listen with different annotations?

## Example:

```
@Inject
@EventTest
private Event<String> event;

event.fire("Hello!!!");
```

---

```
public void listener1(@Observes @EventTest String msg) {
    System.out.println("listener1: " + msg);
}
```

---

```
public void listener2(@Observes @OtherEventTest String msg) {
    System.out.println("listener2: " + msg);
}
```

==================================

the event is executed by calling the two listener methods, I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, I was missing the following in the annotations:

---

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD })
```

---

Now it works correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).